# Install nuget package get error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I am trying to install the nuget package `GeoLocation`, `EntityFramework` to my project by using VS 2017 Professional. While I am getting the following error.

> Error  : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for
>   'VizsafeWindows'.

I have tried the following methods but none will work:

- Deleted the %AppData%/Nuget/Nuget.config and restarted the VS .
- Closing and reopening the VS.
- Deleted all the packages and installed once again.

Comment: winform,wpf,umw , which one ?

Comment: and if restore failed, why not try re-downloading em ?

Comment: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/992

Comment: Where is this NuGet package located?

Comment: What is your project type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'VizsafeWindows'.

I have tried install those two packages to different project types, got the same error when I install them to the UWP project. So, Is your project type UWP?

When I open the output window, I will got the following detailed error messages:

[image]

Just as the error message showing, the reason for this issue is those packages are not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586).

To resolve this issue, we have to wait the author of those package to update package to support UWP. You can check the [similar issue](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/745) on the Github.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your machine and then
Fire the command in package manager console
Update-Package –reinstall